# Binding working fine in MainActivity.kt but not working properly on BirthdayGreetingActivity.kt (another activity file). Unresolved reference: inflate

Tags: android, kotlin, binding, android-inflate

I was learning kotlin with binding while MainActivity.kt is working completely fine, when I am trying to do the same steps in another Activity named BirthdayGreetingActivity.kt , `inflate` method is not working and giving error saying
`Unresolved reference: inflate.`
Also at `binding.root`, it is also giving error saying
 `Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: internal val File.root: File defined in kotlin.io`

I already added

```
  buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```

in the build.gradle file.

**this is my MainActivity.kt file -**

```
package com.example.birthdaygreet

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import com.example.birthdaygreet.databinding.ActivityBirthdayGreetingBinding
import com.example.birthdaygreet.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)*/
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

    }

    fun showMessage(view: View) {

        val name = binding.enterNameField.editableText.toString()

       val intent = Intent (this, BirthdayGreetingActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(BirthdayGreetingActivity.NAME_EXTRA, name)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

**and this is my second activity file BirthdayGreetingActivity.kt file -**

```
package com.example.birthdaygreet

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class BirthdayGreetingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val NAME_EXTRA = "name_extra"
    }

    private lateinit var binding: BirthdayGreetingActivity


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthday_greeting)*/
        binding = BirthdayGreetingActivity().inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        val name = intent.getStringExtra(NAME_EXTRA)
        binding.birthdayGreet

    }
}
```

[Red problems screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRtQ4.png)

inflate is showing this error and

[inflate error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aR5k.png)

binding.root is showing this error

[binding.root error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQRBS.png)

None of these error is showing in the MainActivity.kt but only showing in BirthdayGreetingActivity.kt

please help me resolve this issue...

I tried copying everything from MainActivity.kt but it did not worked. I already added

```
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

in Build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.birthdaygreet'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.birthdaygreet"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made the object binding as object of type BirthdayGreetingActivity.
It should be of type layoutbinding.
that is for example:

```
private lateinit var binding: BirthdayGreetingActivityBinding
```

or whatever layout you want to inflate followed by 'Binding' word.

Similarly, for

```
binding = BirthdayGreetingActivity().inflate(layoutInflater).
```

or you can use,

```
override val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> BirthdayGreetingActivityBinding =
        BirthdayGreetingActivityBinding::inflate
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the generated binding class, you're just creating a new `BirthdayGreetingActivity` instance and then trying to call `inflate` on it (which isn't a method on an `Activity)`

```
// wrong (and you should never be constructing Activity objects yourself!)
binding = BirthdayGreetingActivity().inflate(layoutInflater)
```

---

Assuming your layout file is `R.layout.birthday_greeting_activity`, then view binding will generate a binding class called `BirthdayGreetingActivityBinding`. *That class* has a static method `inflate`, which will produce a `BirthdayGreetingActivityBinding` object, and that's what you should be storing.

```
lateinit var binding: BirthdayGreetingActivityBinding

...

binding = BirthdayGreetingActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

And if you look at your working `MainActivity` one, you'll see that's exactly how it's being handled there, with the equivalent binding class